# Footer at bottom of the page with content stretching in between

Tags: html, css

I was trying to implement a footer that remains at the bottom of the page even if the content is not enough to fill the page.

Here is the JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkp9b/)

Although I am able to get the footer to the bottom, I have run into another issue. I want the content to stretch to till the footer, so that background (aliceblue) in the example stretches till the footer. Currently, I am unable to get that working, so I need some help.

Here is the code.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="container"> <!-- Bootstrap specific -->
            <div class="header">Header here</div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>website content here.</p>
                <p>website content here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container"> <!-- Bootstrap specific -->
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Footer Here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -50px; 
    background-color:wheat;
}
.header {
    height:25px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.content {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 50px;
}
.footer {
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Content `<div>` height expands based on the amount of content. Give it a height and it'll move till the footer !

Comment: But that's what I don't know. It will depend upon the actual content of the page!

Answer (score 0):

let's use Stickyfooter =)

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap" class="container">
    <div id="main" class="content">
        <div class="header">Header here</div>
        <p>website content here.</p>
        <p>website content here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer" class="footer">
    <p>Footer Here</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*  
Sticky Footer Solution
by Steve Hatcher 
***
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com
*/
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
html, body {height: 100%;}
#wrap {min-height: 100%;}
#main {
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    }  /* must be same height as the footer */
#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -50px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 50px;
    clear:both;} 
/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {/* thanks to Maleika (Kohoutec)*/
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;/* thank you Erik J - negate effect of float*/
}
/*==========
your styles*/
body {
    background-color:wheat;
    }
.header {
    height:25px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    }
.container {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding:0;
}
.content {
    padding:0 15px;
}
.footer {
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is applying background **aliceblue** to **container** instead of the **content** div. The **container** in my code has its own background (I had not shown since it is gradient background and would have cluttered the code in question). I hope you get the idea.